# how to recover lost wordpress login and password through my hosts cpanel?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have several sites and cannot access them as I have forgot/misplace my login information.  I can get to my cpanel, but it has a lot of different WRP#'4 and I need to figure out which one and then update my login information. How do I find/correct/change my login and password?  This is my first problem and am at a loss on how to access a couple of my sites as I have lost my access spreadsheet info and have to re-do it all.  Thanks to anyone out there that can assist.  I am not a programmer, just a user of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress stores password hashes, so they can't be recovered.  This is by design - storing plaintext or even encrypted passwords is a security risk.

The easiest thing to do is use Wordpress's "forgotten password" feature, assuming that you have control over the email address that the user was created with.

If you don't, you'll need to access the database directly.  The process for doing this will vary by host, but usually there is a way to use PHPMyAdmin from Cpanel.